# apply function to specific cells in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply a function to some cells in a pandas dataframe. Not along a column or row axis, across the entire dataframe, but only some cells.

I have the cell indices stored (in a list of (col, row) tuples, but I can store in any format that would make this question more easily solved).

so for example if my dataframe is:

```
  0 1 2
0 1 2 1
1 2 1 3
2 0 0 1
```

I want to apply `my_func =  lambda x : x+1` (EDIT: or some other my_func, eg `my_func = lambda x : str(x) + str (x) +"!"`, I'm just giving this one as an example because it's easy to show output) to cell indices `[(0,1), (0,2), (1,2)]` to get:

```
  0 1 2
0 1 2 1
1 3 1 3
2 1 1 1
```

is there any better way to do this then to run a loop of `dataframe.iat[col, row]=my_func(dataframe.iloc[col, row])` on my list of index tuples?

(I wanted to try making a function that would check the index against a set of tuples created from the list, and only apply my_func if the index was there, but `apply`, the only bulk application function I could find, runs across an axis, not cell by cell, so there was no way to check the indices...)

Answer (score 1):

Use the underlying `numpy` array:

```
x, y = zip(*idx)
df.to_numpy()[y, x] += 1
```

---

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  1
1  3  1  3
2  1  1  1
```

Comment: thanks, I guess this is my fault for the specific way I phrased the question, but I didn't mean specifically adding 1, I meant any arbitrary function. I've edited to make that more clear, and I'll look into the numpy indexing you've referenced here.

Comment: @dWitty as long as you assign the result of your function to that slice, it doesn't matter what operation you do.